# Installing packages for python3 in Raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, package

I need to run `.py` files by `python3.5` on the `Raspberry-Pi`. Firstly I need to install `packages`, such as `OpenCV` or else.

```
   pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install opencv-python
    Collecting opencv-python
      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
    No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

It worked for `python2` by `pip install opencv-python`. But it doesn't work for `python3`.

`pip3 -V` command shows `pip 10.0.1 from /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)`.
 Is there something I forgot?

Comment: See if it is missing the following apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

Comment: You have always to compile your OpenCV library for RPi. Here's one of many instructions. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/ You have to do it only once, if you take image copy of your SD-card. Takes 4 hours in RPi 3, if you have done it once before...